# Converting string that is dd.mm.yyyy. HH:mm:ss format to datetime C#

Tags: c#, datetime

So I have string that is 24.08.2010. 21:21:21, I want to convert it to 2010-08-24 21:21:21  to be able to  save it in the db.

I tried this

```
var input = "22.08.2010. 7:00:00";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(input,"yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", null);
Console.WriteLine(date);
```

but I get error:

> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Anyone have idea how to convert this?

Comment: Well your input is not the same as your format... so fix that

Comment: You said `So I have string that is 24.08.2010. 21:21:21` but your code has `22.08.2010. 7:00:00`? o.O Also you _really_ have `.` after your year part? That's odd. _Just_ based your input, the right format seems as `dd.MM.yyyy. h:mm:ss`. Also it would be better to use _specific_ `CultureInfo` when you parse your strings to DateTime objects to prevent ambiguous situations.

Comment: Also, you should be saving your dates as the `Date` type in your DB, _never_ save a date as a string

Comment: You need to parse the string using the format the string is currently in, then format the DateTime in the format you want it in.

Comment: Your format string is not right is it? You have `yy` as the first part of the string. The first part is 22 which is a day.

Comment: They are all listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings The inout format string must match the content of the literal text, else the parser will decode it into the wrong chunks and won't be able to construct a date object.

Comment: My mistake, but yes i have . after year part, my string format is  dd.mm.yyy. HH:mm:ss and that is my input that i can't change, but also i can't save it in ms sql server database .

Comment: Parse exact expect to have the Exact format. This part is important so they added it to the function name. You gave `"yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"`.. Is the input date starting with year on 2 digit? Followed by a `"-"`? Yeah you get a format Exception. That pretty self explanatory.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to convert string input into *date*:

```
var input = "22.08.2010. 7:00:00";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "dd.MM.yyyy. H:mm:ss", null);
```

And than convert *date* to string:

```
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
```